# How to start an activity after a preset time in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I have been trying with starting an activity after a pre determined time set by the user.
I have two activities, one is sending some strings to another activity by means of:

```
Intent go = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallComeActivity.class);

            go.putExtra("sub", name);
            go.putExtra("photo_path", fname);
            go.putExtra("text", number);

            startActivity(go);
```

I am receiving these strings using:

```
    String sub = intent.getStringExtra("sub");
    String photo_path=intent.getStringExtra("photo_path");
    String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
```

Now I need to start this second activity after some time.
I have tried with BroadCast Receiver but I am not able to send these strings to the second class using Broadcast Receiver. I am only able to trigger the second class without passing these strings.
Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [AlarmManager..](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), and you can use [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) for putting extras

```
Intent go = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallComeActivity.class);

            go.putExtra("sub", name);
            go.putExtra("photo_path", fname);
            go.putExtra("text", number);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, go, 0);
```

**From the documentation:**

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow
>   you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the
>   future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered
>   for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target
>   application if it is not already running. Registered alarms are
>   retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the
>   device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it
>   is turned off and rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                    // Start your app main activity
                    callIntent();
                }
            }, Your_pre_determined_time);
```

Comment: Thanks but no, I want the second activity to run after some time like 20 minutes. I can't keep running the app for 20 mins. I want something like a background service which comes to foreground after 20mins.

Comment: @DarshanGowda .Have you tried [AlarmManager?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: I am using AlarmManager but I am not able to pass strings to the second class.

Comment: Can you post your code please,might I can help@DarshanGowda

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule an Alarm using AlarmManager and once you get a call to onReceive method of your AlarmReceiver, you can start the activity. But it might look abrupt especially if the user is using some other application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    intent.putExtra(key, value);
                    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext,id, intent, 0);
alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, remindAtTimeStamp, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: I am using AlarmManager and successfully schedule an activity to start but I am not able to pass strings to the second class.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent go = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallComeActivity.class);

        go.putExtra("sub", name);
        go.putExtra("photo_path", fname);
        go.putExtra("text", number);

        startActivity(go);
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, 3000);
```

Try using TimerTask for execute something after a certain time.
I use this for show a splash screen for mi app for tree seconds.